# Bootstrap 4 Nav Bar fixed-top over content

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm using bootstrap4 fixed-top navbar which works fine in normal browser.

However, when I test on a mobile device (Galaxy S5 using chrome dev options) the content starts behind the nav bar, I've tried some padding in my css but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Below is a jsfiddle of the HTML and CSS, the page content starts behind the fixed-top nav bar.

https://jsfiddle.net/8kefh4u7/6/

Also here is my CSS

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.epg-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
}
.epg-container ul.listings-grid {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #262626;
}
.epg-container ul.listings-grid li {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
.epg-container ul.listings-grid .listings-channel-row {
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 6px;
  border-color: #262626;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.epg-container ul.listings-grid .listings-channel {
  /*  color not necesary  */
  color: white;
  width: 20%;
  height: 83px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.epg-container ul.listings-grid .listings-channel img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.epg-container ul.listings-grid .listings-program {
  color: #989898;
  border-right: solid;
  border-right-width: 3px;
  border-left: solid;
  border-left-width: 3px;
  border-color: #262626;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: black;
}
.epg-container ul.listings-grid .listings-details-now-info {
  color: #fa9609;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.epg-container ul.listings-grid .listings-details-next-info {
  color: #fa9609;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

What would be the best way to make the content page always start under the NAVBAR that would work well on mobile.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed this so now the content will always start after the fixed nav bar.

I added the below to the body css

```
min-height: 51.5rem;
padding-top: 2.5rem;
```

Thank you @ZimSystem for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 8):

The recommended method is `padding-top` on the BODY, the same height as the navbar...

```
body {
   padding-top: 56px;
}
```

From the Bootstrap docs..

> "Fixed navbars use position: fixed, meaning they’re pulled from the normal flow of the DOM and may require custom CSS (e.g., padding-top on the ) to prevent overlap with other elements."

Comment: I've tried setting padding-top in the body, which fixes but when I go and change the device that is a difference screen size. It's either behind the navbar still OR there is a big white gap space. Is there anyway to make the content start after the navbar that will work dynamic for all devices?

Comment: With all of the custom CSS you have added it's hard to say. I'd start by using just the Bootstrap classes to get what you want. Also having the BODY as flexbox makes any children of the BODY effected by all of the flexbox properties shrink/grow etc.. This make it all less consistent across browsers.

Comment: It's because of the flex property on the body element that doesn't allow the padding to behave the way it should

Answer (score 5):

It is unreliable to use a fixed amount for the height of the header to introduce a `padding-top` to the `body` element.  I'm using this bit of code after a page refresh to set the body to the correct height.

```
        $("body").css({'padding-top': $('nav.navbar').height()});
```

The navbar is identified using the `nav` element with the `navbar` class.