# Navbar Toggle Button Not Working in Bootstrap v4.1.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using BootstrapCDN v4.1.3 and I want my navbar to be fixed to the top of the user's browser at all times. When I set the `nav` div to `position: fixed;`, none of the links can be clicked on when the browser is in desktop mode and the navbar toggle button does not drop down when the browser is in mobile mode. As soon as I remove the `position: fixed;` CSS attribute, everything works in the navbar, except it is no longer positioned above the stock video and it pushes the video down when the navbar menu is toggled in a mobile browser. This is not my desired result and I would appreciate if someone could help me figure out how to get the navbar to function properly while also maintaining a fixed position at the top of the user's browser.

```css
nav.navbar {
  background-color: rgba(144, 188, 244, .8) !important;
  position: fixed;/* <---- Causing the navbar issue */
  width: 100%;
}

div.stockVideo {
  padding: 0;
}

#stockVideo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
  <title>Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="media/placeholderLogo.png" width="44" height="44" alt="Logo">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Stock video -->
  <div class="container-fluid stockVideo">
    <video autoplay muted loop id="stockVideo">
            <source src="media/stockVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Settings the navbar `z-index:` property to `1` fixes this:

```
nav.navbar {
  background-color: rgba(144, 188, 244, .8) !important;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;

  z-index: 1;
}
```

I'd also set `padding-top` to the height of your navbar on `body` like so:

```
body {
    padding-top: 59px; /* the height of your navbar */
}
nav.navbar {
    top: 0; /* bump the header back to the top */
}
```

Comment: The `z-index: 1;` worked. Thank you. However, I do not want to add `padding-top` because I want my navbar to be on top of the video.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the bootstrap fixed-top class to fix the navbar like

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
```

Comment: I completely forgot about this as this is my first time using bootstrap in awhile. This worked perfectly and saved me a few extra lines of CSS. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add padding to the top of the video to allow for the Navbar height..

```
#stockVideo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/YWnrU7WAXM

Ideally, the body would have padding-top instead as recommended in the Bootstrap docs...

> "Fixed navbars use position: fixed, meaning they’re pulled from the
>   normal flow of the DOM and may require custom CSS (e.g., padding-top
>   on the ) to prevent overlap with other elements."

```
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

This has been [asked and answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101175/bootstrap-4-nav-bar-fixed-top-over-content).

***EDIT***

If you want the Navbar fixed, use the Bootstrap `fixed-top` class. Using `position:fixed` alone won't work because you'd need to also set z-index. As you can see `fixed-top` works here: https://www.codeply.com/go/YWnrU7WAXM

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top bg-light"></nav>
```

Comment: This doesn't account for dynamic content on a page or the fact the some pages will have different content.

Comment: I want my navbar to overlap the stock video and all of the other content on my page while staying fixed to the top of the user's browser, hence why I made it transparent. Also, this question has not been asked before. The question you referred to at the bottom of your answer is not the same as my question, as my navbar links and mobile toggler were not working too due to the `position: fixed` CSS property.

Comment: I was saying that the padding-top aspect has been answered before. If I thought the question was a duplicate, I would have closed it. If you want the Navbar fixed, use the Bootstrap `fixed-top` class. This sets the proper top,right,left and z-index. Using position:fixed alone won't work.